# How to store UUID from one MySQL query and use it in another one by using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this query in my php file:

```
<?php
require_once("database/config.php");

$customerNr = $_POST['customer_nr'];

$customerUuid = '';
$name = '';
$query = "SELECT HEX(uuid) AS customer_uuid, name FROM customers
WHERE customer_number = :customerNr";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->bindValue(":customerNr", $customerNr);
$sql->execute();
if ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $name .= $row["name"];
    $customerUuid .= $row["customer_uuid"];
}
```

When I use `echo "$customerNr<br>$name<br>$customerUuid";` I can see all these data.
Now I want to use `$customerUuid` in another query in the same php file but it's not working.

```
$addressUuid = '';
$street = '';
$zipCode = '';
$city = '';
$query = "SELECT HEX(uuid) AS address_uuid, street, zip_code, city
FROM addresses WHERE customer_uuid = UNHEX(:customerUuid)";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->bindValue(":customerUuid", $customerUuid);
$sql->execute();
if ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $street .= $row["street"];
    $zipCode .= $row["zip_code"];
    $city .= $row["city"];
    $addressUuid .= $row["address_uuid"];
}
```

Could anybody help me how to prepare this query?

Comment: What does it mean it doesnt work?

Comment: Later in my code I have HTML where I display the name, address and other details about customer. When I comment this second query, there will be displayed page with the name of the customer. When I uncomment this query, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Probably because you use the same variable names for query and sql etc

Comment: I tried to rename variables for query and sql. It is still not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25387498/1745672

Comment: Now I've found the bug. Thanks @Mihai.